# Why is every parameter of my "Services" Object working but this one?

Tags: java, arrays, file, object, arraylist

I am creating an Array List differentServices composed of objects Services I am creating.

When I'm trying to get data from a file which would serve as services with parameters service name, service file name, and service fee and while printing the values of my array list differentService I note that the name of the services in my arraylist are all different and according to the file, the service fees of the different objects in the arraylist are all different and according to the file too, but the filename of every object in differentServices is the same even though the way I declare the new Services() is the same as for service name and service fee.

I'm trying to understand why as I need the data of every service to be different.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment2_main {

Services[] a; //a is a Template object
int size;
static String name;
static String fileName;
static double usageFee;
static String toRemoveString = "service=";

 public void ArrayList() {
        a = (Services[]) new Object[10]; //a defined as a list of 10 Objects T
        size = 0;
 }

 public void add(Services item) { //Add item to the end
        if(size == a.length) { //If the size is equal to the length of a
            doubleArray(); //Double the array
        }
        a[size++] = item; //The last object of the array takes the value of item
 }

 public void add(int pos, Services item) { //Add item to specific position
        if(size == a.length) {//Double the array if the size is equal to the length of a
            doubleArray();
        }
        for(int i=size-1; i>pos; i--) { //Every element after the position specified is changing index by one
            a[i+1] = a[i];
        }
        a[pos] = item; //The element at position pos takes the value of item
        size++; //Increment the size
 }

 public Services get(int pos) { //Get value at position pos
        if(pos >= size || pos < 0) { //If the specified position is out of bound, display error
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        return a[pos]; //Return the object at position pos
 }

 public Services remove(int pos) { //Remove element at position pos
        if(pos >= size || pos < 0) { //If the specified position is out of bound, display error
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        Services temp = a[pos]; //temp object T takes value of the element to remove
        for(int i=pos; i<size-1; i++) { //Every element after the position specified is changing index by one
            a[i] = a[i+1];
        }
        size--; //size of the array decrements by one
        return temp; //Return the removed value
 }

 public int size() { //Return the size of the list
        return size;
 }

 void doubleArray() {
        Services[] newArray = (Services[])new Object[a.length*2]; //Doubles the length of the array a
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //places all the elements of the array a into array newArray
            newArray[i] = a[i];
        }
        a = newArray; //places all the elements back into a
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     ArrayList<Services> differentServices = new ArrayList<Services>();

     try {
          File configFile = new File("/Users/Yohan/Desktop/CS245Assignment2/config.txt");
          Scanner scanConfigFile = new Scanner(configFile);
          while (scanConfigFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = scanConfigFile.nextLine();
            String[] token = data.split(",");
            for(int i=0;i<token.length;i++) {
                if(i==0) {
                    name = token[i].replaceAll("service=", "");
                }
                else if(i==1) {
                    fileName = token[i];
                }
                else if(i==2) {
                    usageFee = Double.parseDouble(token[i]);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Logical Error");
                }
            }
            Services newService = new Services(name, fileName, usageFee);
            //Problem before this
            differentServices.add(newService);
            System.out.println(differentServices.get(0).fileName);
          }

          scanConfigFile.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println("An error occurred.");
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

     System.out.println(differentServices.get(0).fileName);

     String userItemInput = "", userSizeInput = "", userQuantityInput = "";
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     while(!(userItemInput.contentEquals("done"))) {
         System.out.println("Enter your next item or 'done':");
         userItemInput = input.nextLine();
            if (userItemInput.contentEquals("done")) {
                continue;
            }
         System.out.println("Size:");
         userSizeInput = input.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Quantity:");
         userQuantityInput = input.nextLine();
     }
 }
}
```

Here is the configuration file:

```
 service=Instacart,instacart.csv,5.99
 service=Prime,amazon.csv,4.00
 service=Safeway,safeway.csv,3.99
 service=GoogleDelivery,google.csv,6.99
 service=Basket,basket.csv,2.50
```

And here is my Service.java file:

```
public class Services {

   public String name = "";
   public static String fileName = "";
   public double usageFee = 0;

   //constructor
   public Services(String name, String fileName, double usageFee) {
        this.name = name;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.usageFee = usageFee;
    }   
}
```

Comment: You declare the fields for the services `name` and `usageFee` the same way, but the field `fileName` is declared as `static`. That means there is only one field `fileName` for all instances of the `Services` class.

Comment: I can't even read that sentence it's so long.

Comment: Pretty dumb mistake... it's late. And sorry @DaveNewton I got lost in trying to explain the weirdness of what I'm trying to do ahah. Thank you guys